# Runtime Location Permission Issue in Android 10

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am building an app where I need to implement a Google Map API. In all the android versions app is working as expected but in SDK 29 or android 10 it is not working. Every time I grant location permission it again ask for the location permission, I have even manually grant the permission but still, it's not working. Here is my code:

```
  public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Grant Permission")
                    .setMessage("Location Permission Required")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    //Request location updates:
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.

            }
            return;
        }

    }
```

I am calling this method in onCreate in an activity.

Comment: What exactly not working for you ?

Answer (score 1):

1) In menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

2) Inside Activity

I) Define globally inside activity

```
private static final int PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT = 105;
private SharedPreferences permissionStatus;
String[] permissionsRequired = new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
};
```

II)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    permissionStatus = getSharedPreferences("permissionStatus", MODE_PRIVATE);
    checkPermission();
}
```

III) Create a method

```
public void checkPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(BaseMapActivity.this, permissionsRequired[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(BaseMapActivity.this, permissionsRequired[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(BaseMapActivity.this, permissionsRequired[0]) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(BaseMapActivity.this, permissionsRequired[1])) {

            boolean foreground = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean background = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            if (foreground || background) {
                proceedAfterPermission();
            } else {
                androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(BaseMapActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need App Location Permission");
                builder.setMessage("App name need location permission to show your current location.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BaseMapActivity.this, permissionsRequired, PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(permissionsRequired[0], false) && permissionStatus.getBoolean(permissionsRequired[1], false)) {
            boolean foreground = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean background = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            if (foreground || background) {
                proceedAfterPermission();
            } else {
                androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(BaseMapActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("GPS Not Enabled");
                builder.setMessage("Enable GPS from your setting");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        sentToSettings = false;
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BaseMapActivity.this, permissionsRequired, PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
        }

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = permissionStatus.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(permissionsRequired[0], true);
        editor.commit();
    } else {
        proceedAfterPermission();
    }
}
```

IV)

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT) {
        boolean allgranted = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
            if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                allgranted = true;
            } else {
                allgranted = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (allgranted) {
            proceedAfterPermission();
        } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(BaseMapActivity.this, permissionsRequired[0])
                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(BaseMapActivity.this, permissionsRequired[1])
        ) {
            boolean foreground = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean background = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            if (foreground || background) {
                proceedAfterPermission();
            } else {
                androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseMapActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need App Location Permission");
                builder.setMessage("App name need location permission to show your current location");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BaseMapActivity.this, permissionsRequired, PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        } else {
            proceedAfterPermission();
        }
    }
}
```

V)

```
private void proceedAfterPermission() {
   //Do your stuff after permission
}
```